# is there a way to move mysql database from Windows(Wamp) to Ubuntu(Xamp)?

Tags: mysql, database, ubuntu, import, export

I have mysql database which I created using phpMyAdmin on Windows(Wamp). The database has over 2million records. Anytime I run a query either through CLI or phpMyAdmin, the query takes a very long time to execute. So I want to move my database from Windows to Ubuntu system with higher capacity. Kindly advise me on the best way to go about this. Thank you.

Comment: If you have phpmyadmin on LAMP as well (Ubuntu) you can also use the GUI to export and import if that's more convenient for you. I have not tried it with as many records but in principal I don't think there would be a problem.

Comment: Thanks @Khanal, using GUI option did not work in my case because of the large amount of data involved. However, I will explore the option of mysqldump through a secure SCP.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to dump the contents of your database, move the contents to your new location and then upload them to the new database. More details can be found [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-migrate-a-mysql-database-between-two-servers).

Comment: thanks for your direction. I hope it work well for me. I will give it a trial.